# How to apply multiple regex patterns in pyspark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to implement a udf which takes input Dataframe and column name every record in the input column has to parse through all the regular expression pattern. I'm new to pyspark.

```
import re
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

def group_nm_transfrom(inDF,column_name):
    column_name = re.findall(r's/ AND /  /', column_name)
    column_name = re.findall(r's/ ADVANCED | ADVANCE / ADV /', olumn_name)
    column_name = re.findall(r's/ ASC | ASSOCI | ASSC | ASSOCIAT | ASSOCIA | ASSO | ASSOCS | AS | ASSOCIATES / ASSOC /', column_name)

    return matches[0] if matches else None
```

Comment: You don't need to use `udf` for this- you can use [`pyspark.sql.Column.rlike()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Column.rlike) and [`pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_extract()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_extract)

Comment: Please provide some sample input/desired output. More on [how to create good reproducible apache spark dataframe examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48427185/how-to-make-good-reproducible-apache-spark-dataframe-examples).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I have an issue with regex extract with multiple matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54597183/i-have-an-issue-with-regex-extract-with-multiple-matches)