# I have an issue with regex extract with multiple matches

Tags: pyspark

I am trying to extract 60 ML and 0.5 ML from the string "60 ML of paracetomol and 0.5 ML of XYZ" . This string is part of a column X in spark dataframe. Though I am able to test my regex code to extract 60 ML and 0.5 ML in regex validator, I am not able to extract it using regexp_extract as it targets only 1st matches. Hence I am getting only 60 ML.

Can you suggest me the best way of doing it using UDF ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is how you can do it with a python UDF:

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
import re

data = [('60 ML of paracetomol and 0.5 ML of XYZ',)]
df = sc.parallelize(data).toDF('str:string')

# Define the function you want to return
def extract(s)
    all_matches = re.findall(r'\d+(?:.\d+)? ML', s)
    return all_matches

# Create the UDF, note that you need to declare the return schema matching the returned type
extract_udf = udf(extract, ArrayType(StringType()))

# Apply it
df2 = df.withColumn('extracted', extract_udf('str'))
```

Python UDFs take a significant performance hit over native DataFrame operations.  After thinking about it a little more, here is another way to do it without using a UDF.  The general idea is replace all the text that isn't what you want with commas, then split on comma to create your array of final values.  If you only want the numbers you can update the regex's to take 'ML' out of the capture group.

```py
pattern = r'\d+(?:\.\d+)? ML'
split_pattern = r'.*?({pattern})'.format(pattern=pattern)
end_pattern = r'(.*{pattern}).*?$'.format(pattern=pattern)

df2 = df.withColumn('a', regexp_replace('str', split_pattern, '$1,'))
df3 = df2.withColumn('a', regexp_replace('a', end_pattern, '$1'))
df4 = df3.withColumn('a', split('a', r','))
```

Comment: Thanks Ryan ! Very helpful .. will let you know how it goes

Comment: Pure pySpark solution doesnt work for me.  Full match is retained. You can use $1 to differentiate with the rest of the match (and add before or after) but you cant use it to extract only $1