# How to match regex pattern multiple times in Pyspark?

Tags: regex, pyspark

Below consists of email data present in the single column:

Requirement is to print from Call Example to additional details alone.

Input:

Summary:
Below are the details:

Call Example:
dialFromNumber:***** dialToNumber:***** date:*** time:*** additional details:xxxx

Please check out the call details.

Second Call Example:
dialFromNumber:*****
dialToNumber:*****
date:***
time:***
additional details:xxxx
Some random text.

Output:
Both of the call examples needs to be populated in the new column 'Calldetails1' in two different rows using Pyspark.

Call Example:
dialFromNumber:***** dialToNumber:***** date:*** time:*** additional details:xxxx

Call Example:
dialFromNumber:*****
dialToNumber:*****
date:***
time:***
additional details:xxxx

Regex_extract which i used to print from call example to additional details:

result = df.withColumn('result',regex_extract('comments','(?s)(?=Call Example)(.*?additional details:\s*[\w+])',1))

It's working for one group. Please suggest options to work globally in python

Comment: Do you want to get the data comes after additional details: ??

Comment: @rootkonda: yes. till end of that line.

Comment: it is bit straight forward dont you think ? Or I misunderstood something....doesnt this work for you additional details:(\w+)$ ?

Comment: It isn't working. I do have random text before call details. and even at the end of the column

Comment: Please check here....https://regex101.com/r/yGIz8w/1    

Example I tested is dialFromNumber:***** dialToNumber:***** date:*** time:*** additional details:asjhd and regex is additional details:(\w+)$ and the capture group 1 is asjhd if you are referrring to something else...please edit the post and give us better explanation, input/output u tried etc.,

Comment: edited the problem statement. Kindly have a look.

Comment: additional details:(\w+)$  is fetching only additional details:xxxx

Comment: You can try multiline mode enabled. I started a chat session - https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219127/room-for-rootkonda-and-ss-14. If you are still not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the chat:

```
(?=Call Example)([\w\s:\*]+?[\S])$

(?=Call Example) will assert whether there is a string that starts with Call Example

[\w\s:*]+? - Will do a lazy check of atleast 1 or more characters until the last occurence of a character till end of line.
```

Extracting multiple captured groups using pySpark

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58930893/extracting-several-regex-matches-in-pyspark
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54597183/i-have-an-issue-with-regex-extract-with-multiple-matches
```